# Substituting text in a file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

I need to read in a file which will be in xml format but all crammed into a single line, and I need to parse that line to find a specific property and replace its value with something I have specified.

The file might contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><VerificationPoint type="Screenshot" version="2"><Description/><Verification object=":qP1B11_QLabel" type="PNG">
```

I need to search through this line, find the property "Verification object=" and replace the :qP1B11 with my own string. Please not that I don't want to replace the `_QLabel" type="PNG">` part of the string if possible.

I can't use  **sub**  as I don't value of the property which could be anything, and I believe I should be able to do this with Regular Expressions but I have never had to use them before and all examples I've seen just make me more confused than earlier.

If anyone can present me with an elegant answer (and an explanation if using regexp) it would be a huge help!

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but let us not forget: Parsing XML is a solved problem. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: if you can find the attribute 'object' can you use split('_') on its value to get the string you want to replace? Will this give you what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You have XML so use an XML parser. Nokogiri will make short work of that:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(that_string)
doc.search('Verification').each do |node|
    node['object'] = node['object'].sub(/:qP1B11/, 'PANCAKES')
end
new_string = doc.to_xml
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n<VerificationPoint type="Screenshot" version="2">\n  <Description/>\n  <Verification object="PANCAKES_QLabel" type="PNG">\n</Verification>\n</VerificationPoint>\n"
```

You can adjust the output format using the options for [`to_xml`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-to_xml).

If you only have one `<Verification>` then you could do it like this:

```
node = doc.at('Verification')
node['object'] = node['object'].sub(/:qP1B11/, 'PANCAKES')
new_string = doc.to_xml
```

In either case you'd adjust your regex and replacement to suit your needs.